# Is collision checking easier when using primitves vs equivalent stls (moveit)

Tags: moveit, simulation, stl, collision-detection

I am wondering whether collision checking using primitive shapes (defined in the URDF) is faster than using equivalent .STL or .obj geometries.

With equivalent i mean creating cylinders, spheres and boxes in a cad software to enclose the robot goemetry (in *solidworks* using different [configuratons](https://help.solidworks.com/2021/english/SolidWorks/sldworks/c_Configurations_Overview.htm)  ) and exporting those geometries in .STL files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of collision checking, using primitive shapes (like boxes, cylinders, and spheres) defined in the URDF is faster and more efficient than using equivalent STL or OBJ (mesh) files that represent these geometries.

Primitive shapes have fewer parameters to be considered during collision detection, reducing the computational load. Mesh files, even those representing simple geometries, contain many more data points (vertices and edges), making the collision detection process more resource-intensive because the process will include checking every vertex.

It is recommended to use **meshes for visualization** and **primitive models for collision checking**. Inside the link we have `<visual>` and `<collision>` tags. The `<visual>` is used for rendering robot links in simulations, where the detailed geometry of mesh files is beneficial. The `<collision>` tag defines the geometry used for collision detection, where primitives simplicity is more advantageous due to their lower computation cost.

We can use programs like [MeshLab](https://www.meshlab.net) to see the number of vertices on STL meshes, and we can even use the same software to simplify the mesh, but primitives will still be more efficient.

Comment: So as a rule of thumb:
1) If i do not want very fine collision checking and speed is a priority (the controller may be deployed in a raspberry pi), i should use primitives.
2) If i want to capture some of the collision geometry (let's say the urdf for atlas which moves in unstructured environments), i would use a convex hull approximation from meshlab. (convex to help my solvers too). 
3) The end effector should have more detail 
4) And generally, if i can do my job with primitives, then i should do it with primitives. 
5) Never use visual geometry for collision

Comment: If speed is a priority, using primitives is the better choice. Notice that wrapping the primitive shape well around the link does not sacrifice the quality of collision checking. If the robot has many parts, add finer-sized primitives to cover all parts.